# ADO.NET Retrieve UDT Columns from SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, schema, user-defined-types

I can use code like this to extract the columns from a SQL Server 2012 table:

```
    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(conns);
    var dt =  sqlConnection.GetSchema
(SqlClientMetaDataCollectionNames.Columns, new string[] { null , null ,  "mytable" , null });
```

However, I am unable to determine the right kind of schema query to get the columns from my user-defined Table type. How is that done?

All ideas appreciated (Using .NET 4.5.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is still a relevant question, but I just received an answer to something nearly identical. Check out the answer for this question:

[Retrieve UDT table structure in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608765/retrieve-udt-table-structure-in-vb-net)

The answer shows how to get a "sanitized" type name from sys.types, then it creates simple sql query in the form:

`declare @t MyUDTType; select * from @t;`

Then returns the empty `DataTable` to the calling application.