# Retrieve UDT table structure in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, user-defined-types

In searching for my answer, I saw this question:
[ADO.NET Retrieve UDT Columns from SQL Server 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916472/ado-net-retrieve-udt-columns-from-sql-server-2012) but it remains unanswered. In short, this is my question, but the context is below.

I have a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure that takes two table-valued parameters (TVPs) which I want to call from VB.NET (3.5 now, but I am not married to this). I have used `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters` to determine the parameters of my stored procedure:

```
cmd1 = New SqlCommand()
cmd1.Connection = oCn2 ' assume properly connected to database
cmd1.CommandText = "uspInsertTestData"
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd1)
```

My Stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[uspInsertTestData]
        @Processor varchar(20),
        @TRes [dbo].[TestResultsType] READONLY,
        @EXSetup ExtraTestSetupType READONLY,
        @ErrNum int OUTPUT,
        @ErrString varchar(300) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
-- ... stuff
END
```

And my UDT table types look like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TestResultsType] AS TABLE(
    [ResultValue] [sql_variant] NULL,
    [ResultInfo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ResultUnits] [char](20) NULL,
    [PassedTest] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [TestName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [TestTypeName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MinLimit] [float] NULL,
    [MaxLimit] [float] NULL,
    [UUTTemperature] [float] NULL)

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ExtraTestSetupType] AS TABLE(
    [FieldName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FieldValue] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Units] [char](20) NULL)
```

The call to `DeriveParameters()` populates `cmd1.Parameters` as expected, and I can identify the two UDT table types as well - the `Parameters.TypeName` indicate that they are, in fact, UDT table types - this code:

```
Debug.Print("parameter [" & p.ParameterName & "]: SqlDbType=[" & _
      p.SqlDbType().ToString() & "]: TypeName=[" & p.TypeName() & "])
```

Yields:

```
parameter [@Processor]: SqlDbType=[VarChar]: TypeName=[]
parameter [@TRes]: SqlDbType=[Structured]: TypeName=[LMUTesterData.dbo.TestResultsType]
parameter [@EXSetup]: SqlDbType=[Structured]: TypeName=[LMUTesterData.dbo.ExtraTestSetupType]
parameter [@ErrNum]: SqlDbType=[Int]: TypeName=[]
parameter [@ErrString]: SqlDbType=[VarChar]: TypeName=[]
```

All that said, the questions are:

1: Is there a way to DERIVE the columns of the UDT table types? All the examples I have studied will use `DataTable.Columns.Add()` to add the COLUMNS to the datatables before passing them as parameters to stored procedure. Ideally, I would like to use the `Parameter.TypeName` value to retrieve the structure of the UDT.

2: If the answer to 1 is "NO", when i use `DataTable.Columns.Add()` to build the structure of my UDT, does it have to be in the SAME ORDER as the UDT itself? Given the UDT definition for `TestResultstype` above, is it OK to do:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("TestResultsType"); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("ResultUnits", GetType(string)); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("ResultInfo", GetType(string)); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("ResultValue", GetType(float)); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("TestTypeName", GetType(string)); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("UUTTemperature", GetType(float)); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("MinLimit", GetType(float)); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("MaxLimit", GetType(float));
```

3: Is the only way to do this is to implement as CLR (Common Language Runtime) assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Private Function DataTableForServerType(ByVal Connection As SqlConnection, ByVal ServerTypeName As String) As DataTable

    Dim SanitisedQualifiedTypeName As String

    Using cmd = New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = Connection
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "select top (1) quotename(schema_name([schema_id]), '[') + N'.' + quotename([name], '[') from [sys].[types] where [name] = parsename(@type_name,1) and [schema_id] = isnull(schema_id(parsename(@type_name,2)), [schema_id]) and [is_table_type] = 1;"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@type_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = ServerTypeName

        SanitisedQualifiedTypeName = CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), String)

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(SanitisedQualifiedTypeName) Then
            Throw New Exception(String.Format("Table type '{0}' does not exist or you don't have permission.", ServerTypeName))
        End If
    End Using


    Using ada = New SqlDataAdapter("declare @t " & SanitisedQualifiedTypeName & "; select * from @t;", Connection)
        Dim res As New DataTable

        ada.Fill(res)

        Return res
    End Using

End Function
```

Comment: An interesting note - using sql_variant in the UDT table does not work when trying to populate from VB.NET. I had to change the UDT to be a varchar(50), then use CONVERT(ResultValue, sql_variant) when loading into the table.

Comment: @KeithKibler Yes, [it would appear so](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14148301/11683).